# How to define a custom attribute that can take in multiple references or format-types?

Tags: java, xml, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

I asked chatGPT to show me how to have an attribute that can take in a collection of drawable references for my `CustomView` via xml

here's what it spat out:

for `attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
    <attr name="images" format="reference|reference[]"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

usage in some `xml` layout:

```
<com.example.CustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:images="@drawable/icon1,@drawable/icon2,@drawable/icon3" />
```

retrieval via `constructor`:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);
int[] imageIds = a.getResourceIdArray(R.styleable.CustomView_images);
a.recycle();
```

However I am getting the error `Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@458c701d`, so I am here to ask **humbly** about how to really get this done (if it's possible)